# PEG grammar to parse identifier name which is not a keyword

Tags: parsing, rust, pest

I am using Pest.rs for parsing. I need to parse identifiers but reject them if they happen to be a reserved keyword. For example, `bat` is a valid identifier name but `this` is not since that has a specific meaning. My simplified grammar is as below.

```
keyword = {"this" | "function"}
identifier = {ASCII+}
valid_identifier = { !keyword ~ identifier }
```

This works but it also rejects identifier names like `thisBat`. So basically it checks if that the prefix is not a `keyword`, but I want to check against the full `identifier`.

Comment: It seems that this would only become an issue in cases where identifiers and keywords can occur in the same spot in a valid sentence of the language, so is that the case here?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the example above. It rejects identifier names like `thisBat`.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that identifiers are composed of alphanumeric characters, another option is:

```
keyword = {"this" | "function"}
identifier = @{ !(keyword ~ !ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC) ~ ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC+ }
```

`!(keyword ~ !ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC)` rejects any identifier that starts with a keyword, as long as the character following the keyword can't be part of the identifier itself. This means that `thisBat` is an acceptable identifier, but `this` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a hack to address this.

```
keyword = {"this" | "function"}
identifier = {ASCII+}
valid_identifier = @{ !keyword ~ identifier | keyword ~ identifier }
```

The new second rule in `valid_identifier` takes care of matching with the valid case which the first one rejects. Note I have made `valid_identifier` atomic so that whitespaces are not inserted and the parse output is not like `this` and `Bat`, but a single `thisBat`.